# Validation of viewstate MAC failed and Sys is not defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an application in a web farm that consists of 4 web servers.

Also the IIS version is 6.

The application is live for more than one year and everything went well until the last week were, with no reason, I started to get the following errors.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined**

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined**

Firstly, it came in my mind that something goes wrong with one for the servers,but I checked it out and I found out that this may happened in all the servers randomly. I mean that other times it works and other not.

Also the web config has all the necessary sections.

It's worth mentioned that when I started getting the above errors I started also getting the following.

**Validation of viewstate MAC failed**

Again the same for this. It happened randomly. It's so weird !

Does anyone know why could this happened and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt your Server IIS version is changed, is it?

Comment: No it is not. Also the version is IIS6

Answer (score 0):

Has your traffic increased?  Do you have the same machine key set for each machine in your farm?  You may find that more users are going back to a different server than the one that initially served them.

Good info here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx

Comment: I've add in web config the machineKey. So, every server will encrypt and decrypt the data with the same key. Am I missing something?